# Is it possible to get a list of WI with changes made by a specific user since specific date?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

Is there a way to get a list of workitems with changes made by user X since a specific date? "Changed by = user X AND changed date >= @today - 7", doesn't work, because it shows only work items with a most recent change made by user X. "Changed by WAS EVER user X AND changed date >= @today - 7", also doesn't work, because it will show work items with most recent changes made in the last 7 days, but the changes made by user X could be made potentially 1 year ago.

Basically what I'm looking for:

A query that will use the combination of Changed By(user X) and Changed Date(@Today - 7) that will show me ONLY WorkItem_1, when:

1. WorkItem_1: User X made a change 3 days ago, user Y made a change 2 days ago.
2. WorkItem_2: User X made a change 2 months ago, user Y made a change 2 days ago.

Comment: do you have code  you could provide us? obviously don't reveal the network credentials you're using

Comment: From what I can tell this appears impossible from the query builder. However if you can use the VSTS API, then you can get the full work item history and use that to determine if the last change was made by user X within the last 7 days.

Comment: Thanks @pritaeas, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can to do it through REST API, simple workflow:

1. Get work items through Work item query REST API: [Run a stored query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#run-a-stored-query)
2. Get [updates](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/updates#get-a-work-item-update) or [revisions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/revisions) of these work items
3. Filter work items per to requirement

Comment: This won't help. Considering the part after 'Basically what I'm looking for' - it shows neither WorkItem_1 nor WorkItem_2 and I needed a query that would show me only WorkItem_1.

Comment: @Cogut It seems that you need to do it through API.